# Extend already defined class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

The traditional way of extending classes in JS is something like this:

```
// define constructor function
function Fuu(){}
// extend prototype and override prototype's constructor
Fuu.prototype = Object.create(OtherClass.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        value: Fuu, 
        enumerable: false, 
        writable: true, 
        configurable: true
    }
});
```

**Then** you add the methods you want to the prototype

```
Fuu.prototype.method = function() {}
```

And just like that you have a function extending another. A nice example of inheritance in JS!

My question is how to extend when the sub class already has a prototype with methods and properties. I could try to copy the the methods of the old prototype to the new one using a `for in` loop but the methods are non enumerable(class is created with a transpiler) and doing something with `getOwnPropertyNames` doesn't seem right. Any suggestion? can I do something like keeping the prototype and adding a prototype to the prototype?

*Edit:* example

```
class Fuu {
    someMethod(){} // non enumerable method in Fuu's prototype
}

// My first option: (extending this way `someMethod` is lost)
Fuu.protoype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {//...same as before})

// Option 2: copy methods from old to new prototype

// Option 3: prototype of prototype?
// Fuu.prototype.prototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {...})
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like

```
            ┌──> Fuu.prototype
instances ──┤
            └──> OtherClass.prototype
```

But that's not possible, because objects only have one [[Prototype]].

Therefore, you must achieve one of these:

```
instances ───> Fuu.prototype ───> OtherClass.prototype
instances ───> OtherClass.prototype ───> Fuu.prototype
```

So you must set the [[Prototype]] of one of those to be the other one. I will assume the first possibility.

There are two main ways to set the [[Prototype]]:

- [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), when creating the object

  The problem is that both `Fuu.prototype` and `OtherClass.prototype` have been created already.

  However, you can create a new object with the right [[Prototype]] and assign the properties of the old one.

  Since there may be non-enumerable properties, you must use [`getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames). Using [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and [`getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) may also be a good idea, in case there are getters or setters.

  ```js
  var old = Fuu.prototype,
      props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(old);
  Fuu.prototype = Object.create(OtherClass.prototype);
  for(var i=0; i<props.length; ++i)
     Object.defineProperty(
       Fuu.prototype,
       props[i],
       Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(old, props[i])
     );
  ```
- [`setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) or [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) (ES6), once the object has been created:

  ```js
  Object.setPrototypeOf(Fuu.prototype, OtherClass.prototype);
  ```

  ```js
  Fuu.prototype.__proto__ = OtherClass.prototype;
  ```

  However, be aware that

  > Mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of how
  >   modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, a very slow
  >   operation, in every browser and JavaScript engine. The effects on
  >   performance of mutating prototypes [...] may extend to any code that
  >   has access to any object whose [[Prototype]] has been mutated. If you
  >   care about performance you should avoid mutating the [[Prototype]] of
  >   an object.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'm going for your first option using `getOwnPropertyNames`. I thought I could do something with `Fuu.prototype.prototype` but I didn't realize that `Fuu.prototype` is an instance.

Comment: As @Wio comments I'm also concerned about the constructor property of the old prototype. It's a bit late to think ... copying the old constructor that way is what I want to do?

Comment: @olanod There should be no problem with `constructor`. Since it's an own property, it will be included in the array returned by `getOwnPropertyNames`, so it will be copied. And `setPrototypeOf` doesn't affect own properties.

Answer (score 1):

I think the method you have suggested is probably the bet way to go.  Is there a reason why you think it is wrong?

```
var old = Fuu.prototype;
Fuu.prototype = Object.create(OtherClass.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        value: Fuu, 
        enumerable: false, 
        writable: true, 
        configurable: true
    }
});
var names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(old);
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var name = names[i];
    Fuu.prototype[name] = old[name];
}
```

The only thing I'd be concerned about is your `constructor` method being overridden by the old version, and for your old prototype's prototype chain being lost; however you can do things to fix this.