# Extending defined class. How to call superclass' constructor?

Tags: javascript, class, reflection, extends, es6-class

Given 2 defined classes `M` and `N`, I'd like to make `M` extend `N`.

For that I want to use `setPrototypeOf()` described in [this answer (2nd solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29885803/4600982).

```
Reflect.setPrototypeOf( M.prototype, N.prototype )
```

Also I want that class `M` `constructor()` to  call class `N` `constructor()`.

To achieve that I use the following call:

```
Reflect.construct( Reflect.getPrototypeOf( M.prototype ).constructor, args, M )
```

*Note:* I don't use `N` in `construct()` because I want it to work even when the class is not extended (or extended whith another a class).

It works in my test but I'm not sure it's the best way to do that.

```js
class N {
  constructor() {
    console.log('N created')
  }
  get N() {
    return 'N-prop'
  }
}

class M {
  constructor(...args) {
    console.log('M created')
    return Reflect.construct(Reflect.getPrototypeOf(M.prototype).constructor, args, M)
  }
  get M() {
    return 'M-prop'
  }
}

Reflect.setPrototypeOf(M.prototype, N.prototype)

var m = new M
console.log(m.M, m.N)
```

Is there a better, proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To make `M` extend `N`, first use the `extends` keyword. Then to call a parent class from a child class, use the keyword `super` in the child's constructor.

```
class N {
  constructor() {
    console.log('N created');
  }
  get N() {
    return 'N-prop';
  }
}

class M extends N {
  constructor(...args) {
    console.log('M created');
    super();
  }
  get M() {
    return 'M-prop';
  }
}

const m = new M(); // -> M created
                   // -> N created
```

You mentioned that you want to be able to call `N`'s constructor even if `M` doesn't inherit from `N` - if this is the case, you might want to think about refactoring your code. It seems unusual that you'd want to call another, unrelated classes's constructor function.

Comment: I can't use extends because iI want to extend the class *after* it was defined.